# TabBarView inside Columns

Tags: flutter, dart

Seem I faced with bug in flutter - don't see any normal ways to resolve. Can anybody suggest something?

```
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: getAppBar(localizations),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              ListView(
                children: [
                  Container(color: Colors.green, height: 200,),
                  Container(color: Colors.yellow, height: 200,),
                  Container(color: Colors.red, height: 200,),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TabBarView(
                      controller: _tabController,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      children: [
                        Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 200,),
                        Container(color: Colors.green, height: 200,),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 200,),
                  Container(color: Colors.green, height: 200,),
                  Container(color: Colors.green, height: 200,),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
```

this variant looks better, but doesn't work too:

```
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: getAppBar(localizations),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  children: [
                    Container(color: Colors.green, height: 200,),
                    Container(color: Colors.yellow, height: 200,),
                    Container(color: Colors.red, height: 200,),
                    TabBarView(
                      controller: _tabController,
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      children: [
                        Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 200,),
                        Container(color: Colors.green, height: 200,),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 200,),
                    Container(color: Colors.green, height: 200,),
                    Container(color: Colors.green, height: 200,),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
```

TabBarView is breaking everything, but I needs tabs insides scrollable screen.

P.S. error is na-na classic: `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.`, but it's not the same. Please don't send me links which I have already checked twice.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem was really inside `TabBarView` - by default it thinks that tabs has a dynamic size and don't allow to use them inside column. additionally it doesn't allow to use `Expand`. F***. Anyway, I had found an solution - https://pub.dev/packages/autoscale_tabbarview.